# Load a certain file every MIT-Scheme initialization

Tags: scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

I have a few `.scm` files that have some handwritten functions that I use often. Is there a way I can configure MIT-Scheme to load these files every startup (initialization) ? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the user manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Customizing-Scheme.html#Customizing-Scheme):

> Scheme supports init files: an init file is a file containing Scheme code that is loaded when Scheme is started, immediately after the identification banner, and before the input prompt is printed. This file is stored in your home directory, which is normally specified by the `HOME` environment variable. Under unix, the file is called `.scheme.init`; on the PC it is called `scheme.ini`.

So, create an initiation file that loads your other files (Or put their contents in it; whatever you prefer).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that .. I will load my files using it.